# How do you understand her name "Bi-khim Hsiao"?

Tags: translation, pinyin, romanization

Her name in Chinese is "萧美琴" and in English is "Bi-khim Hsiao". How do you understand the translation?

Comment: "Hsiao Bi-khim" looks like a Taiwanese name, no? [Wade-Giles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wade%E2%80%93Giles) **Hsiao** is just Pinyin **xiāo**,  [**Bi**](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/minyu?kaiOrder=1411) and [**khim**](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/minyu?kaiOrder=2700) both look like [Min](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min_Chinese) pronunciations.

Answer (score 1):

Bi-khim is the romanization of the Taiwanese pronunciation of 美琴。Obviously 萧美琴's parents decided to use Taiwanese, not Mandarin, to transliterate their daughter's name.

Comment: 谁是萧美琴，有链接嘛，老兄！！

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Last name, which is Hsiao, is the language in Hokkien and her father’s last name is Hsiao. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Hsiao Bi-khim (Chinese: 蕭美琴; pinyin: Xiāo Měiqín; Wade–Giles: Hsiao1 Mei3-ch'in2; Pe̍h-ōe-jī: Siau Bí-khîm）

frow wiki: [Hsiao Bi-khim - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hsiao_Bi-khim)